# Precision of Eigensystem?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy

I was using `Eigensystem` to obtain the rotation matrix. However, I find out Mathematica does not fully diagonalize my matrix (or say not precise enough). My matrix is the following

```
TestM={{6.42497*10^-22, -9.48449*10^-24 - 3.32568*10^-23 I, 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {-9.48449*10^-24 + 3.32568*10^-23 I, 6.42497*10^-22, 0., 0., 
  0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
  1.28499*10^-21, -9.48449*10^-24 - 3.32568*10^-23 I, 0., 0.}, {0., 
  0., -9.48449*10^-24 + 3.32568*10^-23 I, 1.28499*10^-21, 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
  1.28499*10^-21, -9.48449*10^-24 - 3.32568*10^-23 I}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., -9.48449*10^-24 + 3.32568*10^-23 I, 1.28499*10^-21}};
```

And I tried

```
{\[CapitalEpsilon], Ev} = Eigensystem[TestM];
R = ConjugateTranspose[Ev] // N;
Rv = Inverse[R] // N; T2 = Rv.(TestM).R;
T2 // MatrixForm
```

And T2 gives me

```
{{1.25561*10^-21 - 2.05712*10^-38 I, 
  0. + 0. I, -1.88079*10^-37 + 1.82417*10^-23 I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I,
   0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 1.25561*10^-21 - 2.05712*10^-38 I, 
  0. + 0. I, -1.88079*10^-37 + 1.82417*10^-23 I, 0. + 0. I, 
  0. + 0. I}, {9.40395*10^-38 - 1.82417*10^-23 I, 0. + 0. I, 
  1.31437*10^-21 - 1.46937*10^-38 I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 
  0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 9.40395*10^-38 - 1.82417*10^-23 I, 
  0. + 0. I, 1.31437*10^-21 - 1.46937*10^-38 I, 0. + 0. I, 
  0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 
  6.13117*10^-22 - 1.91018*10^-38 I, -1.41059*10^-37 + 
   1.82417*10^-23 I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 
  0. - 1.82417*10^-23 I, 6.71878*10^-22 + 1.6163*10^-38 I}}
```

The answer contains some off-diagonal term with two orders smaller than the diagonal terms, which is far less precise than I needed for my calculation. Is there anyway I can improve the calculation precision? Or precisely speaking, make the off-diagonal term to be smaller than `10^-32` ?

Comment: You could try using all rational numbers by applying `Rationalize` to your approximate scalars. The calculation may take longer but it should avoid any approximate zeroes off the diagonal in your resulting system.

Comment: This is not a precision issue. The correct diagonalization formulation will use the transpose of the eigenvectors, not the conjugate-treanspose.

Comment: yep @DanielLichtblau is right, I corrected my code too - see below.

Answer (score 5):

All of your numbers have about the same small factor. Let's say it is `10^-24`.Then doing the same with `10^24 TestM` matrix

```
Ev = Eigenvectors[10^24 TestM];
R = Transpose[Ev];
Rv = Inverse[R];
T2 = Rv.(10^24 TestM).R;
T2 // Chop // MatrixForm
```

gives you a matrix with much smaller off-diagonal terms:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually this gives the same answer as what I had in the question...

Comment: @Dhwister sorry there was a typo - corrected.